# Create th:href based on values from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I'm using this kind of button to redirect in my spring controller, and it works well:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" role="button" th:href="@{/grid/year/2017/month/12}"> 
  <span th:text="#{grid}"></span> 
</a>
```

I need to change the values of `year` and `month` based on values selected in a javascript function like this:

```
$('#year').on('change', function() { 
  var year = $(this).find('option:selected').val(); 
  var selectedYear= $(this).val(); 
});
```

For example, if the `year` selected is `2016` I want to create a `th:href="@{/grid/year/2016/month/12}` so I can redirect to my controller with this values.

Is this possible, or there is another option? Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

If I add an **id**

```
<a class="btn btn-info" id="add" role="button" th:href="@{/grid/year/2017/month/12}"> 
      <span th:text="#{grid}"></span> 
</a>
```

and

```
alert($('#add').attr('role'));
```

I get value: **button**, but not with **th:href**, maybe ":" is the problem.....

Answer (score 0):

You can change year in th:href attribute using jquery as follows:

```
    $('#year').on('change', function() { 
         var year = $(this).find('option:selected').val(); 
         var selectedYear= $(this).val(); 

         var str = $('a').attr('th:href');
         var arr = str.split('/');
         arr[3] = selectedYear;
         newVal = arr.join('/');
         $('a').attr('th:href',newVal);
    });
```

With the above code, href will be changed to "@{/grid/year/2016/month/12}"

Comment: I get undefined

Comment: Have you tried alert for all variables viz selectedYear, str, arr, newVal?